# How do I map different values for a parameter in the same @RequestMapping in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Suppose I have:

```
@RequestMapping(params = "action=nuovoprodotto")    
    public ModelAndView nuovoProdotto(
            @RequestParam(value = "page", required = false, defaultValue = "-1") int page,
            @RequestParam(value = "action") String action,
            @ModelAttribute Prodotto prod, HttpSession session)
            throws Exception {
```

is it possible to map this request to like two or three values of "action" parameter?

I tried many ways like

```
@RequestMapping(params = "action=nuovoprodotto, action=salvaprodotto")
```

or

```
@RequestMapping(params = "action=nuovoprodotto|salvaprodotto")
```

but they don't work... If I can't what are the solutions, besided writing an handler for every single parameter value combination?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try this:

```
@RequestMapping(params = {"action=nuovoprodotto","action=salvaprodotto"})
```

The `params` attribute is actually of type `String[]`, but annotations let you write a `String` in place of a single-element `String[]`, so these two are equivalent:

```
@RequestMapping(params = {"action=nuovoprodotto"})
```

and

```
@RequestMapping(params = "action=nuovoprodotto")
```

**Reference:**

- [`@RequestMapping.params()`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#params%28%29)

---

Update: my bad, as you can read in the section [Advanced @RequestMapping options](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-advanced), multiple params are combined using and, not or, so it can't work as specified above.

So I'd say what you have to do is  create an alias method with almost the same signature:

```
@RequestMapping(params = "action=nuovoprodotto")    
public ModelAndView nuovoProdotto(
        @RequestParam(value = "page", required = false, defaultValue = "-1") int page,
        @RequestParam(value = "action") String action,
        @ModelAttribute Prodotto prod, HttpSession session)
        throws Exception {
        // some stuff here
}

@RequestMapping(params = "action=salvaprodotto")    
public ModelAndView salvaProdotto(
        @RequestParam(value = "page", required = false, defaultValue = "-1") int page,
        @RequestParam(value = "action") String action,
        @ModelAttribute Prodotto prod, HttpSession session)
        throws Exception {

        return nuovoProdotto(page, action, prod, session);
}
```

Comment: the solution you proposed is the obvious one I ended up using. Thanks anyway for you effort :)