# How to write controller class to allow content-type: application/json and application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: java, json, spring, rest

I am sending request to my controller class request as content-Type: application/json and application/x-www-form-urlencoded format It should allow both types.

But when I am using request type as a application/x-www-form-urlencoded it is working but  when I use request application/json this code is not working it is giving 400 response status. How to solve this issue.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use "consumes" Annotation Element for your request's "Content-Type" header and "produces" Annotation Element for your request's "Accept" header:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/home",
               method = RequestMethod.POST,
             consumes = {"application/json", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"},
             produces = "application/json")
```

ref: [Annotation Type RequestMapping](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html)

These RequestMapping elements is available for Spring 4. If you use Spring 2, then you need to use "params" element, instead of "consumes" & "produces" elements:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/home",
               method = RequestMethod.POST,
               params = {"content-type=application/json",
                         "content-type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                         "Accept=application/json"})
```

check similar question: [How do I map different values for a parameter in the same @RequestMapping in Spring MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4877250/how-do-i-map-different-values-for-a-parameter-in-the-same-requestmapping-in-spr)

Comment: For this we need to add any dependency...?

Comment: Yes, Spring 4.* , I updated my answer in respect of your question. For Spring 4 please follow this guide: https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

Answer (score 1):

use Oauth2 token

```
:  public void login()
    {
        string userName = "abc@mailinator.com";
        string password = "Pass@123";
        //var registerResult = Register(userName, password);

        //Console.WriteLine("Registration Status Code: {0}", registerResult);

        string token = GetToken(userName, password);
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("Access Token:");
        Console.WriteLine(token);


        Dictionary<string, string> tokenDic = GetTokenDictionary(token);

        GetUserInfo(tokenDic["access_token"]);

    }


    private const string baseUrl = "http://localhost/WebApplication4";
    static string GetToken(string userName, string password)
    {
        var pairs = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>( "grant_type", "password" ), 
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>( "userName", userName ), 
            new KeyValuePair<string, string> ( "password", password )
        };

        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(pairs);
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var response = client.PostAsync(baseUrl + "/Token", content).Result;
            return response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        }
    }


    static Dictionary<string, string> GetTokenDictionary(string token)
    {
        // Deserialize the JSON into a Dictionary<string, string>
        Dictionary<string, string> tokenDictionary = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(token);
        return tokenDictionary;
    }

    static HttpClient CreateClient(string accessToken = "")
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(accessToken))
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =
                new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
        }
        return client;
    }

    static string GetUserInfo(string token)
    {
        using (var client = CreateClient(token))
        {
            var response = client.GetAsync(baseUrl + "/api/Account/UserInfo").Result;
            return response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        }
    }
  <form id="form1" action="@ViewBag.Action" method="POST">
    <div>
        Access Token<br />
        <input id="AccessToken" name="AccessToken" width="604" type="text" value="@ViewBag.AccessToken" />
        <input id="Authorize" name="submit.Authorize" value="Authorize" type="submit" />
        <br />
        <br />
        Refresh Tokensh Token<br />
        <input id="RefreshToken" name="RefreshToken" width="604" type="text" value="@ViewBag.RefreshToken" />
        <input id="Refresh" name="submit.Refresh" value="Refresh" type="submit" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <input id="CallApi" name="submit.CallApi" value="Access Protected Resource API" type="submit" />
    </div>
    <div>
        @ViewBag.ApiResponse
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Get refrash token

```
  :  public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.AccessToken = Request.Form["AccessToken"] ?? "";
        ViewBag.RefreshToken = Request.Form["RefreshToken"] ?? "";
        ViewBag.Action = "";
        ViewBag.ApiResponse = "";

        InitializeWebServerClient();
        var accessToken = Request.Form["AccessToken"];
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken))
        {
            var authorizationState = _webServerClient.ProcessUserAuthorization(Request);
            if (authorizationState != null)
            {
                ViewBag.AccessToken = authorizationState.AccessToken;
                ViewBag.RefreshToken = authorizationState.RefreshToken;
                ViewBag.Action = Request.Path;
            }
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Form.Get("submit.Authorize")))
        {
            var userAuthorization = _webServerClient.PrepareRequestUserAuthorization(new[] { "bio", "notes" });
            userAuthorization.Send(HttpContext);
            Response.End();
        }
        else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Form.Get("submit.Refresh")))
        {
            var state = new AuthorizationState
            {
                AccessToken = Request.Form["AccessToken"],
                RefreshToken = Request.Form["RefreshToken"]
            };
            if (_webServerClient.RefreshAuthorization(state))
            {
                ViewBag.AccessToken = state.AccessToken;
                ViewBag.RefreshToken = state.RefreshToken;
            }
        }
        else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Form.Get("submit.CallApi")))
        {
            var resourceServerUri = new Uri(Paths.ResourceServerBaseAddress);
            var client = new HttpClient(_webServerClient.CreateAuthorizingHandler(accessToken));
            var body = client.GetStringAsync(new Uri(resourceServerUri, Paths.MePath)).Result;
            ViewBag.ApiResponse = body;
        }

        return View();
    }

    private void InitializeWebServerClient()
    {
        var authorizationServerUri = new Uri(Paths.AuthorizationServerBaseAddress);
        var authorizationServer = new AuthorizationServerDescription
        {
            AuthorizationEndpoint = new Uri(authorizationServerUri, Paths.AuthorizePath),
            TokenEndpoint = new Uri(authorizationServerUri, Paths.TokenPath)
        };
        _webServerClient = new WebServerClient(authorizationServer, Clients.Client1.Id, Clients.Client1.Secret);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can define consumes attribute in @RequestMapping and ViewResolver in xml.
below:

1. @RequestMapping(consumes = [])
2. ContentNegotiatingViewResolver

Comment: I think there is no need to ViewResolver! Just "consumes" Annotation Element is enough.